# Python: Assignment issues

Tags: python, function, variable-assignment, runtime-error

I had a script which I developed in `/var/tmp` and worked... when I moved to the required directory for some reason it returns the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tail.py", line 104, in <module>
    test=isItAlive(line)
  File "tail.py", line 55, in isItAlive
    return test
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'test' referenced before assignment
```

The function it is moaning about is:

```
def isItAlive(text):
        with open(valcsv) as f:
                searches = [x.split(',')[1] for x in f.read().splitlines()]
                for search in searches:
                #       print search
                        if not search in text:
                                test="TOBEADDED"
                        else:
                                test=search
                                break
                return test
        f.close()
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but I'm pretty sure calling `close()` on a file opened with `with` is redundant.

Comment: Also just noticed that your `return` statement is inside your `with` block.  Probably not the safest thing to do, as it might short circuit `with`'s automatic cleanup.  It also means that your `f.close()` is doubly redundant, since it will never be called.

Comment: @sr222 No, it won't short-circuit `with`'s cleanup. `with` is nicer alternative to the older pattern of cleaning up files using `try/finally`. It provides the same guarantees as `finally` in ensuring that the cleanup code is run "on the way out" regardless how execution leaves the block. Otherwise it would be fairly pointless; it's *easy* to ensure files are closed under the assumption that nothing exceptional happens.

Comment: @Ben Fair enough.  I'd still contend that it looks a bit odd though.  And it still makes `f.close()` doubly redundant.

Comment: @sr22 `return` in a `with` doesn't seem odd to me, but that's purely a matter of taste. The `close` is definitely a bit silly.

Comment: Okay I will take this into consideration... I'm still learning my way through python... I thought it made sense to close an open file. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `searches` value is empty, so the `for` loop never assigns a value to `test`.

Initialize `test` at the start of your function:

```
def isItAlive(text):
    test = None
```

and figure out why your `valcsv` file is empty.

Comment: Thanks... I moved the script but forgot to move the csv... OOPSS!

Answer (score 3):

If `searches` is an empty list, the whole loop will be skipped and `test` will never be initialized.  You need to declare `test = None` or something to that effect before the loop.

Comment: Thanks... I moved the script but forgot to move the csv... OOPSS!